# Clojure database unit testing / mocking

Tags: database, testing, clojure, mocking

I just recently started working on a database-heavy Clojure application and am attempting to get some unit tests in place. Ideally, I'd like to avoid actually hitting a real database by mocking things out.

Here's an example of a simple test:

test-core.clj

```
(deftest core-test
  (is (> (count (fn-under-test "foo")) 0)))
```

core.clj

```
(defn fn-under-test [slug]
  (db/query "select * from %1" slug))
```

db.clj

```
(defn query [q & args]
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results res
      [(clause q args)]
      (doall res))))
```

My question: is there a way, from within test-core.clj, to bind a custom function to 'db/query' such that core.clj will use it, as opposed to the definition within db.clj?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [binding](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/binding) to try and override db/query, but you'll need to define the namespace and var first. The easiest way is to import the db.clj into the same namespace and then use bindings.

```
(ns test-core
    (:use clojure.test)
    (:require db))

(deftest core-test
  (binding [db/query (fn [query & args] (comment return some value here))]
    (is (> (count (fn-under-test "foo")) 0))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I attempted to use binding (and with-binding) earlier today, but couldn't make a go of it -- I kept getting  _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve var: db/query in this context_.

Comment: You could try requiring the db.clj in your test, then use bindings.

Comment: Note: since Clojure 1.3 the `binding` can only work if the var was declared with dynamic meta data. Use `with-redefs` instead to avoid the issue.